# LinQ nested collection query

Tags: c#, linq, collections, nested

I am new to Linq and cannot resolve following problem. Tried checking a lot on internet but did not get proper answer.

I have following query:

```
var packages = from p in Packages
               from cl in p.Categories
               from temp in Clusters
               where (cl.Id == temp.Key)
               select p;
```

Categories is a collection of objects containing id and name. Clusters here is a dictionary of key and value pairs. I get following error when executing this query:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2'. 
>   Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

The other option is to add a for each loop for each category in package as well. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: In your dictionary. what is the type of the Key. What is the type of the value. Can you provide the definitions for Packages, Categories & Clusters in your sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var packages = Packages.Where( 
                   p => p.Categories.Any( 
                   c => Clusters.ContainsKey(c.Id)));
```

If you want each package just once in the result.
It is also more efficient, since ContainsKey is O(1) instead of O(Clusters.Count) in your question.

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I had to realize the sequence into a List and enumerate using ForEach for each package. :(

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the query with the [Dictionary.ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method?

```
var packages = from p in Packages
               from cl in p.Categories
               where Clusters.ContainsKey(cl.Id)
               select p;
```

Comment: Thanks Vedran, I am afraid that may not be the solution. The problem is how to "intersect" the two collections here namely categories and clusters. If the intersection for that package contains some objects, then I select that package. I am not able to put this in a cleaner syntax.\

Comment: The code will do just that. By using the ContainsKey method, you don't have to iterate through the dictionary.