# Extract a new object by matching a common property between an IQueryable<T> and a Dictionary<String, String>

Tags: c#, linq

I have an scenario where I need to generate a new `List<my_custom_object>` by extracting, on the basis of a common column, matched properties between an `IQueryable<T>` and a `Dictionary<String, String>`.

Here is my Dictionary:

```
DirectoryProfilePropertiesCollection = (Dictionary<String, String>)ApiMethods.GetProfileProperties(OrganizationIdentifier, DirectoryIdentifier, DirectoryUserName, DirectoryUserPassword);
```

This returns following information:

```
Key: samAccountName, Value: hgulzar 
Key: sn,             Value: Hassan
Key: lastname,       Value: Gulzar
```

The key here is called Attribute Name.

I also have an `IQueryable`:

```
var DirectoryMappingsCollection = repository.GetQuery<OrganizationDirectoryMapping>(where => where.OrganizationDirectory.Organization.OrganizationUnit.UnitIdentifier == OrganizationIdentifier && where.OrganizationDirectory.DirectoryIdentifier == DirectoryIdentifier);
```

The `OrganizationDirectoryMapping` entity has a property called `DirectoryAttribute`

Both collections have data when I'm to match them. The `DirectoryProfilePropertiesCollection`'s pair has `AttributeName` and `AttributeValue`. The `DirectoryMappingsCollection`'s entity, `OrganizationDirectoryMapping`, has `AttributeName` and `DetailName`

I need to get a custom class object that represents: `DetailName`, `DirectoryAttribute`, and `AttributeValue`

Been trying a few queries but got stuck when I got the exception:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

The question [LinQ nested collection query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11431244/481656) made a bit of sense of the exception but I'm still stuck.

Regards.

What I've tried so far:

```
combinedCol = (from mapCol in DirectoryMappingsCollection
                                                join propCol in DirectoryProfilePropertiesCollection
                                                on mapCol.DirectoryAttribute equals propCol.Key
                                                select new CombinedMappingDataCollection
                                                {
                                                    DetailName = mapCol.DetailRequirement.DetailName,
                                                    AttributeName = propCol.Key,
                                                    AttributeValue = propCol.Value
                                                }).ToList();
```

Comment: what are the queries you have been trying?

Comment: The last promising query I tried, I've updated question above

Comment: And did that query give the exception shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the DirectoryMappingsCollection is coming from Entity Framework, you can't include Dictionarys in the query. Entity Framework can't transform the KeyValuePair to actual SQL-code.

You can add a .ToList to DirectoryMappingsCollection to force it to fetch the entire table in your query and it should work. If you are dealing with large datasets, adding a .Where() to limit the data is recommended.

```
combinedCol = (from mapCol in DirectoryMappingsCollection.ToList()
               join propCol in DirectoryProfilePropertiesCollection
               on mapCol.DirectoryAttribute equals propCol.Key
               select new CombinedMappingDataCollection
               {
                   DetailName = mapCol.DetailRequirement.DetailName,
                   AttributeName = propCol.Key,
                   AttributeValue = propCol.Value
               }).ToList();
```

See [linq to entity framework: use dictionary in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638859/linq-to-entity-framework-use-dictionary-in-query) for a simular question.

Comment: Oh. I totally forgot about that. I knew that one. had faced it so often. Thanks.